# InternalError : Could not follow the item http://webapp/sites/sites

Tags: sharepoint-server, following, homepage, 2019, follow

i would like to use the [SharePoint Homepage](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/sites/enable-sharepoint-home-page-in-sharepoint-server-2019-farms) in SharePoint 2019,
but when i try to follow a site, i get the error

> InternalError : Could not follow the item http://webapp/sites/site

The ULS has the following entry:

> Exception occured in scope
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.FollowedContent.Follow.
>   Exception=Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.FollowedContentException:
>   InternalError : Could not follow the item http://webapp/sites/site
>   at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.FollowedContent.FollowItem(FollowedItem
>   item, Boolean isInternal)     at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.FollowedContent.DoLocalFollow(Uri
>   url, FollowedItemData data)     at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.FollowedContent.Follow(Uri url,
>   FollowedItemData data)     at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.FollowedContentServerStub.InvokeMethod(Object
>   target, String methodName, XmlNodeList xmlargs, ProxyContext
>   proxyContext, Boolean& isVoid)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerStub.InvokeMethodWithMonitoredScope(Object
>   target, String methodName, XmlNodeList args, ProxyContext
>   proxyContext, Boolean& isVoid)

The Managed Metadata Service Application, User Profile Service Application and Search Service Application are all up and running, the service accounts of the application pools of the service applications have permissions on the webapp and the content-database of the webapplication - so what is the issue?

Answer (score 1):

looks like it is permission issue or connection issue with either Mysite or UPA Because user's social activity stored inside the UPA . I would check following:

- Make Sure application pool account of the Content Web Application (from where user want to follow the document) Should have the permission on the MySites content database.
- Make Sure application pool account of the Content Web Application have permission in inside the User Profile Service.

I will also check the ULS logs (may be enable the Verbose logging) and check the complete trace.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - but that did not fix the issue ..

Answer (score 0):

To troubleshoot the issue, you could check if you have created the MySite.

And then check if you have set the site collection administrator in the MySite.

More reference:

[SharePoint: Users cannot create new subsites.](http://www.sharepointblogs.be/blogs/vandest/archive/2015/07/13/sharepoint-users-cannot-create-new-subsites.aspx)